# Can't undertsand why single array inside state is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm learning react and redux and can't seem to understand why a simple array in my state is not functioning right but if I add just another variable which is not even being used then every thing works fine. This is my store:

```
const store = createStore(
reducer,
{items:[],
a:100
}
```

This is the mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
list:state.items,
a:state.a
};
};
```

This is what my reducer return:

```
return {a:state.a-1000,
items:state.items}
```

The variable 'a' is not being used but for some reason if I remove it from the above code blocks then the application does not function correctly. In the reducer's return statement even if I change state.a-1000 with state.a it stops functioning correctly. I can't seem to understand what is happening. The state works fine when there is just a variable in it that is not an array but when there is just an array inside the state for some reason it is requiring another variable.

Comment: change the reduer return statement to return { a: state.a-1000, items: ...state.items } and check

Comment: @GangadharGandi: that gives error : Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Comment: Sorry, return { a: state.a-1000, items: [...state.items] }

Comment: @GangadharGandi it's working now. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redux state needs to be immutable. `items:state.items` mutates the state which wont be picked up by redux.

try `{...state, items}` (where `items` is the new list) or try using Immutable.JS

further info here - https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data